# Как сделать чтоб команда document.execCommand('bold', false, null) работала только на одну строку

Tags: javascript, html

Вот код:

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');

let redactor = document.querySelector('#redactor');
redactor.onmouseup = function(e) {
    let s = '';

    if (window.getSelection()) {
         s = window.getSelection().toString();

    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != 'Contol') {
         s = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    if (s.replace(' ', '') != '') {
        document.execCommand('bold', false, s);
    }
}
```

Я передаю отрезок выделенной строки, но все равно bold начинает работать на весь contenteditable div.

Comment: `document.execCommand` - deprecated (устаревший) метод, его использование не рекомендовано т.к. его нет в веб стандартах, хоть браузеры и могут поддерживать его.

Comment: @ΝNL993 а как можно его заменить?